# Camel cxfrs service not get hit

Tags: java, rest, cxf, apache-camel

I'm using `Camel Java DSL` archetype template. My route builder is like;

```
public class SampleRouteBulider extends RouteBuilder {
    private static final String CXF_RS_ENDPOINT = "cxfrs://http://localhost:8088?resourceClasses="
        + SampleResource.class.getName();
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(CXF_RS_ENDPOINT)
            .choice()
                .when(header(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME).isEqualTo("sample"))
                    .bean(SampleImpl.class, "sample");

    }

}
```

Do I need to register route or something? My service won't get hit.

```
public class SampleResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/sample/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sample() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try use a URI path element like in `http://localhost:8088/rest?esourceClasses=`?

Comment: no. I think it is't mandatory to use /rest

Comment: Maybe, but did you try?

Comment: The `/rest` shouldn't be required, but the configuration of your `SampleResource` is important too, can you include that ?

Also you might want to add `log()` before the `choice()` to confirm the service is not being reached.

Comment: @bgossit Sorry about late response. What you mean by configuration of `SampleResource`? I'll put my `SampleResource` class.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of things that could be wrong here.

1. If you're getting a `404-NOT FOUND`, please make sure you have added the route to the Camel Context. Or else the rest endpoint would not work.
2. If you're getting back a `500`, it would mean that there's an error in your route or CXF bean and you may need to fix that.

If there's anything else apart from these two, please mention the exact response that you're getting back from the server.

Comment: I won't get any response at all.